# access variable by pressing address

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner and I want to use instance `w` of `OlMainWindow` in order to access `_x` by pressing address (`OlMain->vref->_x=10;`) through `ui_MainWidow::setupUI()` function, but when I compile this program then I get an error on line `OlMain->vref->_x=10`:

```
error: use of undefined type 'OlMainWindow'
```

Please help me fix this error.

ui_MainWidow.h

```
#ifndef UI_MAINWINDOW_H
#define UI_MAINWINDOW_H
#include <iostream>
#include "olvalue.h"

class OlValue;
class OlMainWindow;
class ui_MainWidow;

class ui_MainWidow {
public:

    void setupUI(OlMainWindow* OlMain) {
        OlMain->vref->_x=10; // _x = 10;
        OlMain->vref->_x = 10;
        std::cout << " ok";
    }
};
#endif //UI_MAINWINDOW_H
```

olvalue.h

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef VALUE_H
#define VALUE_H

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
class OlValue;
class OlMainWindow;
class ui_MainWidow;

class OlValue
{
public:
    int _x;
    int _y;
public:
    OlValue() {
        _x = 10;
        _y = 20;
    }
};
#endif //VALUE_H
```

olmainwindow.h

```
#ifndef OLMAINWINDOW_H
#define OLMAINWINDOW_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "olvalue.h"

class OlValue;
class OlMainWindow;
class ui_MainWidow;

class OlMainWindow
{
public:


    OlValue* vref = new OlValue;

    OlMainWindow();
    ~OlMainWindow();

    void enterUsername();
private:    
    int val;
    std::string _Username;
};
#endif //OLMAINWINDOW_H
```

olmainwidow.cpp

```
#include "olmainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class OlValue;
class OlMainWindow;
class ui_MainWidow;

OlMainWindow::OlMainWindow() {
    ui_MainWidow* ui = new ui_MainWidow();
    ui->setupUI(this);

}
OlMainWindow::~OlMainWindow() {
    //delete ui;
}

void OlMainWindow::enterUsername() {
    std::cout << "Please, enter Username: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, _Username);
    std::cout << "You'v accessed Username: " << _Username << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "olmainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    OlMainWindow* w = new OlMainWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error, but have no explanation yet. I am looking into it.

Comment: How were you able to fix it? By not providing an inline definition of the function `ui_MainWidow::setupUI`, instead defining the function outside the definition of `ui_MainWidow`? Or did you fix it another way? By the way, you are allowed to write an answer for your own question.

Comment: i just move the definition of setupUI(...) to the appropriate .cpp, 
beauce i build this same as Qt UI, but Qt setupUI function in header file, i dont know how they make it

Comment: Yes, that is also what I would have recommended.

Answer (score 1):

In `ui_MainWidow.h`, the implementation of `setupUI()` is inlined, but when it tries to access the members of `OlMainWindow` it fails because the `OlMainWindow` class hasn't actually been defined yet, merely forward declared.

Your files are not setup correctly.  You are creating dependencies where they don't belong, and then you are trying to use forward declarations to solve circular dependencies issues that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Try this instead:

OlValue.h

```cpp
#ifndef OLVALUE_H
#define OLVALUE_H

class OlValue
{
public:
    int _x = 10;
    int _y = 20;
};

#endif //OLVALUE_H
```

ui_MainWindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef UI_MAINWINDOW_H
#define UI_MAINWINDOW_H

class OlMainWindow;

class ui_MainWindow {
public:
    void setupUI(OlMainWindow* OlMain);
};

#endif //UI_MAINWINDOW_H
```

ui_MainWindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include "OlMainWindow.h"
#include <iostream>

void ui_MainWindow::setupUI(OlMainWindow* OlMain) {
    OlMain->vref->_x = 10;
    OlMain->vref->_x = 10;
    std::cout << " ok";
}
```

olMainWindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef OLMAINWINDOW_H
#define OLMAINWINDOW_H

#include "OlValue.h"
#include <string>

class ui_MainWidow;

class OlMainWindow
{
public:
    OlValue* vref = new OlValue;

    OlMainWindow();
    ~OlMainWindow();

    void enterUsername();
private:    
    ui_MainWidow* ui;
    int val;
    std::string _Username;
};

#endif //OLMAINWINDOW_H
```

olMainWindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "olMainWindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

OlMainWindow::OlMainWindow() {
    ui = new ui_MainWindow();
    ui->setupUI(this);
}

OlMainWindow::~OlMainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

void OlMainWindow::enterUsername() {
    std::cout << "Please, enter Username: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, _Username);
    std::cout << "You'v accessed Username: " << _Username << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "olMainWindow.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    OlMainWindow w;
    w.enterUsername();
    return 0;
}
```